# Uma aplicacao para varios banco de dados!

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Pessoal alguem teria um exemplo ai sobre varios acessos em um sistema web?
 ou seja eu tenho varios banco de dados na nuvem , aii os usuarios vao entrar com seus logins e senha e cada um fica no seu banco de dados , alguem tem algum em referente a esse tipo de conexao ????? hj eu passo o emf por sessao , so q acho q isso nao e o indicado!!!

Answer (score -2):

Voce precisa de um banco de dados geral onde armazena as informações do usuario, por exemplo

usuario, email, senha, banco

Na coluna banco você verifica qual é o banco de dados do usuario e então faz a conexão com o segundo banco de dados...

Comment: isso eu ja tenho !! eu tenho o banco de dados chamado gestor, que tem os dados dizendo emqual servidor o banco esta e o caminho do banco de dados , aii eu tenho o banco de dados do cliente q tem os dados do usuario e senha

Comment: o problema é q vou ter varios usuarios conectando ao mesmo tempo , ou seja , do jeito q eu estou fazendo ele mantem a ultima conexao